# Hide div when clicking outside the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, visibility

I am quite new to Javascript (intermediate in HTML & CSS), though I am pretty good at working things out on my own by looking up other's examples. Unfortunately, I am having significant trouble with this one.

I have a table displaying 3 links to the viewer. Each link when clicked, slides a hidden div open to the right. When one of the other links are clicked, the opened div slides back to being hidden, and then the other one slides open.

What I am looking for, is to hide the divs again when the mouse is clicked on the link again, and also when the mouse is clicked outside the div (or anywhere on the page, really).

I have tried using "e.stopPropagation" but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated - thank you.

I have a jsFiddle that I created for practice:
http://jsfiddle.net/AuU6D/3/

This is my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('a.panel').click(function () {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active'),
            animIn = function () {
                $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                    left: -($target.width())
                }).animate({
                    left: 0
                }, 500);

            };

        if (!$target.hasClass('active') && $other.length > 0) {
            $other.each(function (index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: -$this.width()
                }, 500, animIn);                
            });
        } else if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            animIn();

    }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('a.panel').click(function () {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active'),
            animIn = function () {
                $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                    left: -($target.width())
                }).finish().animate({
                    left: 0
                }, 500);

            };

        if (!$target.hasClass('active') && $other.length > 0) {
            $other.each(function (index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: -$this.width()
                }, 500, animIn);                
            });
        } else if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            animIn();
        } else if ($target.hasClass('active')) {
                $target.removeClass('active').finish().animate({
                    left: -$target.width()
                }, 500);                
        }

    });

    $(document).click(function(e){
        var $target = $(e.target), $active = $('div.panel.active');

        if($active.length && $target.closest('a.panel').length == 0 && $target.closest($active).length == 0){
                $active.removeClass('active').finish().animate({
                    left: -$active.width()
                }, 500);                
        }
    })

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KCYTz/)

Comment: Hi Arun, thanks so much. This works the way I want it to in jsFiddle, but I can't get it to transfer to the browser. Would it have anything to do with the script being in the head tag?

Comment: @user2716530 does not seems to be as the code is in dom ready handler... which portion of the code is not working

Comment: @user2716530 also check the browser console to see whether there is any error

Comment: When I click on the links, nothing happens.
I've never used the error console before, though I had a look and it says Object has no method 'finish'.

Comment: @user2716530 looks like you are using jQuery < 1.9 so instead of `.finish()` use `.stop(true, true)`

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/AuU6D/4/)

```
 $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (!$(e.target).hasClass('panel')) {
            $('div.panel').removeClass('active').removeAttr('style').css('background', ' #e4e4e4');
        }
    });
```

or

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/AuU6D/5/)

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    console.log($(e.target).hasClass('panel'));
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('panel')) {
        $('div.panel.active').removeClass('active').finish().animate({
            left: -$('#right').width()
        }, 500);
    }
});
```